# How to show the selected label instead of the value in an Orbeon field

Tags: xpath, dropdown, orbeon

I would like to recuperate the label selected for databound dropdownlist (`control-4`) in a field. None of the following works:

```
xxf:itemset('control-4','json',true)/itemset/choices/item[@selected = 'true']/label


xxf:itemset('control-4','xml',true)/itemset/choices/item[@selected = 'true']/label


xxf:itemset('control-4','xml')//item[@selected = 'true']/label
```

Changing `@selected = true` to `@selected'selected'` didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
xxf:itemset('dropdown-control', 'xml', true())//item[@selected = 'true']/label
```

Note that:

- when using Form Runner, if the control name is `foo`, then the control id is `foo-control`
- the XPath boolean value for "true" is `true()`

Also note that if you use `xxf:itemset()` in a Calculated Value formula, it might be out of sync with the value of the control, because it introduces a dependency of the data model on the control, like in [this example](https://gist.github.com/ebruchez/04fad358bd52a83dedf6ca688e72e019).

Comment: thanks ebruchez , but can i show the current label not the ancient ?

Comment: it worked for me when i put it in the value attribute in the input !! thanks a lot ebruchez ;)

Comment: That's right, if you use `<xf:output value="...">` then this is evaluated in the view and you can avoid the issue. The problem is that you make a custom change to the form then. Maybe there should be official support for that.

Comment: Found that there is already issue [#1671](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1671) about this.